# Difference between "or" and "add" for assignments in MIPS?

Tags: mips

These instructions can help in assignments (`$s0 = $s1`) in MIPS:

- `add $s0, $s1, $zero` (which is the same as the pseudo-instruction `move $s0, $s1`)
- `or $s0, $s1, $zero`

I'm not sure if there is any difference between these two instructions. And which one is better to use in general case? (I saw some examples usually using the `or` operator to implement this, but I don't know why.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`ADD` will perform arithmetic, e.g. `2 + 3 = 5`

`OR` will perform bitwise OR, e.g. `0b0011 | 0b0110` gives `0b0111`

ADDing zero will look the same as an OR with zero. e.g.

```
5 + 0 = 5 (ADDing 5 and 0)
0b0101 | 0b0000 = 0b0101 (ORing 5 with 0)
```

ADDing a non-zero number may not provide the same result as OR. e.g.

```
5 + 1 = 6
0b0101 | 0b0001 = 0b0101 (5 OR 1 gives 5)
```

Comment: Thank you. But I know the basic principle of these two operator. So, according to your answer, there is no difference when using them with `$zero`, right?